# Qual a melhor ferramenta para realizar um integração de Javascript com MySQL?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

estou programando um sistema de ponto eletrônico web, estou no inicio ainda e meu conhecimento com programação web ainda está no começo. Inicialmente desenvolvi a parte de front-end por HTML e então comecei a pensar na parte do back-end.

Eu estava utilizando firebase como back-end (scripts direto no Javascript) mas acabei desistindo por alguns problemas e com pesquisas vi que não era a melhor maneira para ser feito. Eu tenho conhecimento em MySQL e pensei em utilizar como back-end e o Javascript como front-end, porém não encontrei nenhuma ferramenta que possa fazer isso para mim.

Pesquisei sobre Node.js mas pelo o que encontrei o inicio era desenvolvido por APIs. Então eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de utilizar o Javascript com mais alguma ferramenta para se comunicar com o banco de dados (MySQL) de forma que eu possa aproveitar as telas (forms) já feitas em HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente alguns conceitos precisam ser consolidados. O que você faz no *frontend* não influencia o que você faz no *backend* e vice-versa. Ambas as partes se comunicam através de um protocolo que ambos entendem e que não depende da implementação (é uma especificação em comum).

O *frontend* será responsável por gerar uma requisição HTTP e esperará receber uma resposta HTTP; o *backend* esperará receber uma requisição HTTP e irá gerar uma resposta HTTP. Ou seja, para o *frontend* não importa quem é o *backend*, desde que ele saiba analisar requisições HTTP; para o *backend* não importa quem é o *frontend*, desde que faça requisições HTTP e saiba lidar com as respostas geradas.

Portanto, a pergunta sobre o que usar no *backend* para não perder o que foi feito no *frontend* não faz sentido. Você pode utilizar Node JS, PHP, Python, C#, C, Java, o que preferir no *backend* e isso não interferirá nas decisões do *frontend*.

E não, Node JS não é utilizado apenas para APIs. Você pode servir páginas com ele sem problemas e se comunicar com o MySQL sem muita dificuldade. Existem [muitos pacotes](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mysql) do Node que interagem com o MySQL.

Comment: Tudo bem então digamos que eu escolha o Node.js, eu vi alguns exemplos e a forma que eram feitos era via console. 

Desenvolviam comandos de conexão com o banco e comandos de por exemplo criar uma tabela em um arquivo Javascript e mandava ele executar por meio de um comando no console (ex: node create-table.js). Eu preciso entender como realizar isso de forma "automática". O que eu estou pensando é: o usuário interagi com a pagina em um form, eu obtenho esses dados pelo Javascript e envio para o banco utilizando o node.js.

Eu quero entender como fazer isso corretamente e de forma segura.

Comment: @TiagoAbdalla Se entendeu bem a resposta, a pergunta que deve ser feita será "como processar uma requisição HTTP com Node?". Busque responder isso e sanará as suas dúvidas.

Answer (score -2):

vou deixar aqui minha opinião como resposta, já que não é uma dúvida específica.

**Resposta: Backend em PHP para trabalhar com MySQL**

Vou te dar 4 motivos razoáveis:

1. O MySql têm uma ferramenta ótima para administrar o banco, feita em PHP, inclusive, que é https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
2. Há muita documentação e kilos de tutoriais abordando o relacionamento entre PHP e MySQL, então, é mais difícil você travar por não ter documentação ou onde recorrer quando têm dúvidas (ps.: pesquise aqui no StackFlow por exemplo pela tag PHP e outras possíveis l linguagens para ver a diferença de material)
3. PHP têm funções específicas para trabalhar com MySQL, por exemplo:

   new mysqli("localhost","root","");
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_query();
   mysql_real_escape_string();

Comment: Como a resposta é baseada em opinião, deixei meu negativo por não concordar com ela. Não acho que os três itens listados justifiquem o uso de PHP no *backend*.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ok

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, eu particularmente só usei o nodejs para notificações, gostei do seu link com os módulos, vou baixar depois, obrigado pela opinião

Comment: Apenas justificando melhor agora que tenho mais tempo: o item (1) cita o PHPMyAdmin, mas esse é apenas um cliente MySQL escrito em PHP, não interfere na decisão da linguagem de *backend*; pode, inclusive, utilizar outra linguagem no servidor e utilizar o PHPMyAdmin (embora eu não recomende isso); (2) ok, essa talvez seja uma justificativa, pois, de fato, PHP é uma das linguagens com curva de aprendizado bem pequena, mas no final acaba sendo mais prejudicada do que beneficiada com isso [...]

Comment: [...] dado que a grande parte do conteúdo sobre PHP na internet é escrito por quem não entende o que está escrevendo. Para um usuário novo tirar proveito é necessário ter um mínimo de conhecimento para entender o que deve ser filtrado e, por ser novo, isso é um obstáculo no aprendizado; (3) Possuir nativamente funções para se trabalhar com o MySQL é um facilitador, mas não chega a ser uma justificativa. Outras linguagens também possuem ou possuem pacotes muito bem consolidados na comunidade que fazem o serviço.

Comment: Fora isso, no item (3) você acabou misturando a API `mysqli` com a `mysql`; dada que a segunda é obsoleta e nem existe mais no PHP 7, acaba confundindo bastante.